# Counting multigraphs up to isomorphism

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, graph-theory

> **Problem:** Let $a_m$ denote the number of multigraphs without loops on 4 vertices with $m$ edges (counting up to isomorphism). Find closed formula for the power series $\sum \limits _{m=0}^\infty a_mx^m$.

- I just could not come up with a recurrent formula.
- I know I could employ the Burnside's theorem. If I considered $S_4$'s action on the set of all suitable multigraphs and calculated the number of graphs fixed by each $\sigma \in S_4$, this would be easy, but the overall solution would be tedious given there are $4!$ elements in $S_4$. (Now this could probably somehow be simplified to discuss only types of permutations in $S_4$, but that's still not quite what I want.)
- I cannot guess the solution from the first few members for small $m$. Not even after generalizing this problem to $n$-vertex multigraphs and considering sequence $a_{n,m}$ and looking at small values.
- **Edit:** I am also considering taking the $11$ simple graphs on $4$ vertices and trying to obtain multigraphs by summing them, but I can't get it to work properly.

I am looking for a hint, not for a solution. Ideally, I'd love to obtain the recurrence and apply generating functions to find a closed formula.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consult the following link on how to compute the cycle index $Z(G)$ of
the      edge      permutation      group     of      $K_4$:      [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599675/). (We would not
be adding anything here as we would essentially quote it verbatim.) It
was found that

$$Z(G) = \frac{1}{24}
\left(a_1^6 + 8 a_3^2 + 9 a_1^2 a_2^2 + 6  a_2 a_4\right).$$

As a  sanity check  let us compute  non-isomorphic colorings  of $K_4$
using at most $N$ colors. We get using Burnside the count

$$\frac{1}{24}
\left(N^6 + 8 N^2 + 9 N^4 + 6  N^2\right)
= \frac{1}{24}
\left(N^6 + 9 N^4 + 14 N^2\right)$$

which yields the sequence

$$1, 11, 66, 276, 900, 2451, 5831, 12496, 24651, 45475, \ldots $$

which points us to [OEIS A063842](https://oeis.org/A063842) where this
sequence  is  described  as  the  number of  multigraphs  rather  than
colorings, a  claim that has  to be investigated.  (**Remark, somewhat
later.** This  issue has  now been  fixed.) With this  in mind  we now
compute (use PET rather than Burnside for generating functions)

$$[z^n] Z(G)\left(\frac{1}{1-z}\right)$$

which has OGF as requested in the problem statement

$$\frac{1}{24}\frac{1}{(1-z)^6} + \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{(1-z^3)^2}
+ \frac{3}{8}\frac{1}{(1-z)^2}\frac{1}{(1-z^2)^2}
+ \frac{1}{4}\frac{1}{1-z^2}\frac{1}{1-z^4}.$$

The repertoire  that goes into PET  represents the fact  that there is
exactly one multi-edge consisting of $q$ single edges, yielding an OGF
of $\sum_{q\ge  0} z^q  = 1/(1-z),$ which  includes the off  edge with
weight zero (no edge present between pair of vertices).

This yields the sequence

$$1, 3, 6, 11, 18, 32, 48, 75, 111, 160, 224, 313, 
420, 562, 738, \ldots$$

which points us  to [OEIS A003082](https://oeis.org/A003082). This has
a perfect match to the problem  definition and it looks like the first
entry needs to be qualified or possibly even corrected.

The values  look good,  e.g. the six  multigraphs with  three edges
are: a path, a tree with three leaves, a triangle, a double edge and a
single edge, not  connected, a double edge and  a single edge attached
at one of the vertices of the double one and a triple edge between two
vertices.

Extracting coefficients  is not terribly rewarding here  but we may
use     the     Maple     code     from     the     following     [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2078090/)  to  get  the
set   of   polynomials   (period    due   to   roots   of   unity   is
$\mathrm{lcm}(2,3,4) = 12):$

```
               5          4   13   3         2   1309     53
  n -> 1/2880 n  + 1/192 n  + --- n  + 7/32 n  + ---- n + ---
                              288                2880     192

                5          4   13   3         2   203     13
   n -> 1/2880 n  + 1/192 n  + --- n  + 7/32 n  + --- n + --
                               288                360     24

                5          4   13   3         2   181     39
   n -> 1/2880 n  + 1/192 n  + --- n  + 7/32 n  + --- n + --
                               288                320     64

                5          4   13   3         2   203
   n -> 1/2880 n  + 1/192 n  + --- n  + 7/32 n  + --- n + 2/3
                               288                360

               5          4   13   3         2   1309     53
  n -> 1/2880 n  + 1/192 n  + --- n  + 7/32 n  + ---- n + ---
                              288                2880     192

                5          4   13   3         2   27
   n -> 1/2880 n  + 1/192 n  + --- n  + 7/32 n  + -- n + 7/8
                               288                40

               5          4   13   3         2   1309     53
  n -> 1/2880 n  + 1/192 n  + --- n  + 7/32 n  + ---- n + ---
                              288                2880     192

                5          4   13   3         2   203
   n -> 1/2880 n  + 1/192 n  + --- n  + 7/32 n  + --- n + 2/3
                               288                360

                5          4   13   3         2   181     39
   n -> 1/2880 n  + 1/192 n  + --- n  + 7/32 n  + --- n + --
                               288                320     64

                5          4   13   3         2   203     13
   n -> 1/2880 n  + 1/192 n  + --- n  + 7/32 n  + --- n + --
                               288                360     24

               5          4   13   3         2   1309     53
  n -> 1/2880 n  + 1/192 n  + --- n  + 7/32 n  + ---- n + ---
                              288                2880     192

                 5          4   13   3         2   27
    n -> 1/2880 n  + 1/192 n  + --- n  + 7/32 n  + -- n + 1
                                288                40
```

The Maple code for this goes as follows:

```
HZ := 1/24*1/(1-z)^6+1/3*1/(1-z^3)^2
+3/8*1/(1-z)^2*1/(1-z^2)^2+1/4*1/(1-z^2)*1/(1-z^4);

PSEQ :=
proc()
    option remember;
    local n, lambda, offs, res, locs, vals, cfs;

    res := [];
    lambda := lcm(2,3,4);

    cfs := series(HZ, z=0, 6*lambda+2);

    for offs from 0 to lambda-1 do
        locs := [seq(offs+p*lambda, p=0..5)];
        vals := map(loc -> coeff(cfs, z, loc), locs);

        res :=
        [op(res),
         unapply(interp(locs, vals, n), n)];
    od;

    res;
end;

X :=
proc(n)
    local Fseq, lambda;

    Fseq := PSEQ();
    lambda := nops(Fseq);

    Fseq[1+(n mod lambda)](n);
end;
```

**Addendum.**  Some  additional  material  which may  perhaps  inspire
further exploration  of these types  of problems.  Here is  a
routine  for  computing  the  cycle  indices  of  the  edge
permutation group  of the complete graph  $K_n.$ It is  about twice as
fast    as    the   routine    posted    at    the   following    [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314103/), which includes
some explanatory  material. We obtain  e.g. the following  cycle index
for $K_6:$

$$Z(G_6) =
{\frac {{a_{{1}}}^{15}}{720}}+1/48\,{a_{{1}}}^{7}{a_{{2}}}^{4}+1
/18\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{3}}}^{4}+1/12\,{a_{{1}}}^{3}{a_{{2}}}^{6}
\\+1/4\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}{a_{{4}}}^{3}+1/6\,a_{{1}}a_{{2}}{a_{{3}}}^{
2}a_{{6}}+1/5\,{a_{{5}}}^{3}\\+1/18\,{a_{{3}}}^{5}+1/6\,a_{{3}}{a_
{{6}}}^{2}.$$

This can of course be used to count multigraphs. Working with ordinary
graphs we obtain the generating function

$$Z(G_6)(1+z) = 
{z}^{15}+{z}^{14}+2\,{z}^{13}+5\,{z}^{12}+9\,{z}^{11}+15\,{z}^{
10}+21\,{z}^{9}\\+24\,{z}^{8}+24\,{z}^{7}+21\,{z}^{6}+15\,{z}^{5}+
9\,{z}^{4}+5\,{z}^{3}+2\,{z}^{2}+z+1$$

for a total  of $156$ graphs.  E.g. the  nine non-isomorphic graphs on
six  vertices with  four edges  would appear  to be,  singletons being
omitted: the  path on five vertices,  a tree with four  leaves, a tree
with three leaves, a square, a  triangle with a node attached to it, a
path on  four nodes and  one on two  nodes, a triangle and  a detached
connected pair, a tree with three leaves and a connected pair, and two
paths on three nodes.

The  code follows.  Do  consult it  to clarify  the details  of the
technique being used, it is  included here in place of introducing new
notation to describe the algorithm.

```
pet_cycleind_symm :=
proc(n)
option remember;

    if n=0 then return 1; fi;

    expand(1/n*add(a[l]*pet_cycleind_symm(n-l), l=1..n));
end;

pet_cycleind_edg :=
proc(n)
option remember;
local all, term, termvars, res, l1, l2, inst1, u, v,
    uidx, vidx;

    if n=0 or n=1 then return 1; fi;

    all := 0:
    for term in pet_cycleind_symm(n) do
        termvars := indets(term); res := 1;

        # edges on different cycles of different sizes
        for uidx to nops(termvars) do
            u := op(uidx, termvars);
            l1 := op(1, u);
            
            for vidx from uidx+1 to nops(termvars) do
                v := op(vidx, termvars);
                l2 := op(1, v);

                res := res *
                a[lcm(l1, l2)]
                ^((l1*l2/lcm(l1, l2))*
                  degree(term, u)*degree(term, v));
            od;
        od;

        # edges on different cycles of the same size
        for u in termvars do
            l1 := op(1, u); inst1 := degree(term, u);
            # a[l1]^(1/2*inst1*(inst1-1)*l1*l1/l1)
            res := res *
            a[l1]^(1/2*inst1*(inst1-1)*l1);
        od;

        # edges on identical cycles of some size
        for u in termvars do
            l1 := op(1, u); inst1 := degree(term, u);
            if type(l1, odd) then
                # a[l1]^(1/2*l1*(l1-1)/l1);
                res := res *
                (a[l1]^(1/2*(l1-1)))^inst1;
            else
                # a[l1/2]^(l1/2/(l1/2))*a[l1]^(1/2*l1*(l1-2)/l1)
                res := res *
                (a[l1/2]*a[l1]^(1/2*(l1-2)))^inst1;
            fi;
        od;

        all := all + lcoeff(term)*res;
    od;

    all;
end;

pet_varinto_cind :=
proc(poly, ind)
local subs1, subs2, polyvars, indvars, v, pot, res;

    res := ind;

    polyvars := indets(poly);
    indvars := indets(ind);

    for v in indvars do
        pot := op(1, v);

        subs1 :=
        [seq(polyvars[k]=polyvars[k]^pot,
             k=1..nops(polyvars))];

        subs2 := [v=subs(subs1, poly)];

        res := subs(subs2, res);
    od;

    res;
end;

VGF :=
proc(n)
option remember;
    expand(pet_varinto_cind(1+z, pet_cycleind_edg(n)));
end;
```

**Remark.** I only just now noticed  that the OP was asking for a hint
rather than a  solution. It is hoped that there  are enough details to
be filled in here for it to be instructive to assemble a comprehensive
answer.

**Addendum Nov 18  2018.** The result for the number of ordinary graphs is shown below. It is perfectly sufficient to use the Maple functions
**degree** and **indets**  to implement an interface  to the monomials
from the cycle index as multisets of cycles. This is shown below:

$$1, 2, 4, 11, 34, 156, 1044, 12346, 274668, 12005168,
\\ 1018997864, 165091172592, 50502031367952,
\\ 29054155657235488, 31426485969804308768,
\\ 64001015704527557894928, \ldots $$

which points us to [OEIS A000088](https://oeis.org/A000088). The Maple code is (Burnside)

```
Q := proc(n)
local cind, v;
option remember;

    cind := pet_cycleind_edg(n);
    subs([seq(v = 2, v in indets(cind))], cind)
end proc;
```