# Counting number of simple graphs with 'n' unlabelled vertices.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I am aware that the number of simple graphs possible with $n$ labelled vertices is $2^{n(n-1)/2}$.
Is there any closed formula for the same problem with $n$ unlabelled vertices?
In case of unlabelled vertices we have to eliminate graphs that are isomorphic.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This is [A000088](http://oeis.org/A000088)  There are some formulas given, but I think they are all asymptotics.  I don't see an explicit closed-form formula.

Comment: The following [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088991/) may prove useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a formula for the counting polynomial using Polya’s Enumeration Theorem as explained in $(3)$ of http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SimpleGraph.html