# Find a generating function for unlabeled graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, generating-functions, planar-graphs, polya-counting-theory

Let's take a graph(undirected) of $m$ edges and $3$ vertices. Now I want to derive a polynomial for which the coefficient of $x^m$ denotes the number of unlabeled graphs of $m$ edges.

How to derive the polynomial in this case? Also is deriving a polynomial means deriving a generating sequence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we require the cycle index of the action on the edges of the
symmetric group  $S_3$ on the vertices. We find:

- The identity: $a_1^3.$
- Three reflections: $3 a_1 a_2.$
- Two rotations: $2 a_3.$

We get for the cycle index

$$Z(G_3) = \frac{1}{6} ( a_1^3 + 3 a_1 a_2 + 2 a_3 ).$$

Evaluate at $1+z$ for the generating function:

$$Z(G_3; 1+z) = \frac{1}{6}
((1+z)^3 + 3 (1+z) (1+z^2) + 2 (1+ z^3))
\\ = \frac{1}{6}
(1+3z+3z^2+z^3 + 3+3z^2+ 3z + 3z^3 + 2+2z^3)
=  1 + z + z^2 + z^3.$$

This means there is one graph on three vertices taking into account
ismorphisms having  zero, one, two and three edges.

The general case is described and implemented at the following [MSE
link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088991/).