# Number of colorings of a complete graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, coloring

This surely is well known, but googling gave too much false positives. Let $K_n$ be the complete graph with $n$ vertices. (Which has $e=n(n-1)/2$ edges.) Now "edge coloring" was defined as "no touching colors on any vertex", but I'm interested in the much simpler "ignore that restriction". Obviously, there are $m^e$ unrestricted edge colorings of $K_n$ with $m$ colors (if you distinguish vertices), but many of them are topologically indistinguishable under vertex swaps. Example: $K_4, e=6$ has $6$ unrestricted bicolorings ($6/0: 1,5/1: 1,4/2: 2,3/3: 2$).

At the moment I'm only interested in the $m=2$ formula, but surely the general one is known anyway.

Comment: Maybe you mean $m^e$? And in your example shouldn't the bicolorings be $7$ (you have 7 choices for the number of edges of the first colour)?

Comment: Silly me, corrected. Also one bicoloring is invariant under color swap, thus I miscounted.

Comment: The post [How many $2$-edge-colorings of $K_n$ are there?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/314103/how-many-2-edge-colourings-of-k-n-are-there?noredirect=1&lq=1) addresses $m=2$ but the Polya enumeration theorem gives the generalization for all $m$ almost immediately. Note that the top answer counts colorings where vertices are indistinguishable but the colors are distinguishable; see Chris Godsil's answer for the correction to apply if you only want to count colorings up to color swaps, which it looks like you do.

Comment: See also the computations [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/599675),
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088991), and
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3914145).

Comment: Ah, I *knew* this must have been adressed before even here, alas, the "suggested questions" gizmo failed again...Sorry!